# Update DataGrid styling on key press

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, datagrid

I have a DataGrid that styles the background of rows based on if the row is listed as "to delete".
The rows change colour when loading into the table and when scrolling around, but do not immediately change.

I use "ctrl+del" to mark the selected rows for deletion.
How can I get the row to update on this keypress?

DataGrid Implementation

```
            <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="0">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="WhiteSmoke" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <DataTrigger Value="True">
                            <DataTrigger.Binding>
                                <Binding>
                                    <Binding.Converter>
                                        <local:IsDeletedConverter/>
                                    </Binding.Converter>
                                </Binding>
                            </DataTrigger.Binding>
                            <DataTrigger.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="OrangeRed"/>
                            </DataTrigger.Setters>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                    <Setter Property="Background">                        
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <Binding Path="">
                                <Binding.Converter>
                                    <local:ValueToBrushConverter/>
                                </Binding.Converter>
                            </Binding>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

Converter

```
 public class IsDeletedConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (values is ExpandoObject eo)
            {
                if ((Application.Current.MainWindow as MainWindow).LoadedTable.ToDelete.Contains((int)ExpandoUtils.GetExpandoProperty(eo, "id")))
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Replace the `ExpandoObject` with an object of a custom type that implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and raise the `PropertyChanged` event for an `IsDeleted` property that you bind to in the `Style` instead of binding to the object itself.

Comment: @mm8 I can't use a defined type for the data as it needs to be dynamically created from files that are read in

Comment: So create an instance of the type when the file is read dynamically?